# Why does Numpy's RGB array representation of an image have 4 layers not 3?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, colors, vision

Shouldn't there be 3 layers one for the intensity of red, one for the intensite of green and one for the intensity of blue? Then why does the shape of my RGB array say: (73, 115, 4)?

Comment: Google for RGBA.

Comment: Is the image a PNG with transparency? 4-channel arrays are R, G, B, with an "alpha" channel for the transparency.

Comment: Check the docs for `cv2.cvtColor()`. Or you can just drop the fourth channel, which is the transparency. You can just index your image to do that, i.e. `img = img[:, :, :3]`

Comment: that is what i needed alex.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a default transparency column.
This is called the `alpha` value, and defaults to `1`. You can change it of course in one of multiple ways. For instance:

```
plt.imshow(my_im, alpha=0.3)
```

This can be useful for overlaying images one on top of the other, just as an example.
Good luck!

---

Due to another question in the comments: If you want the RGB values, just take the first three columns; e.g. `my_color[:, :, :3]`

Comment: People were asking if i was using png. They were right, I was applying np.array() on the png file. Would using a different image file have given me different formats like RGB instead of GRB or maybe not having the transparency values?

Comment: That's not a matter of the `np.array()` part. It's more a matter of how the file was saved and what module you're using to read it. Some file formats support and some don't support a 4th alpha channel. I'd google it or open a different question on the topic if that doesn't help, because it isn't strictly a python question anymore...